# What do we mean by $\hat{L}$ in Akaike's information criterion?

Tags: statistics, regression

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion),

> "Let hat $\hat{L}$ be the maximum value of the likelihood function for the model."

To me, $\hat{L}$ should have two values, $\hat{\beta_0}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}$ in the simple linear case,

$$\hat{Y} =\hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1}X $$

Would someone be able to explain precisely what is meant by $\hat{L}$ in AIC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y_i|x_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i, \sigma^2)$, then its likelihood is given by 
$$
\prod_{i=1}^n f(y_i ;x_i) = \prod \frac{1}{\sqrt { 2\pi \sigma ^2} }\exp\left\{-\frac{(y_i - \beta_0-\beta_1x_i)^2}{2\sigma^2 }\right\},
$$
plug in the OLS (MLE) of $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ and $\sigma^2$ - and you get the maximum value of the likelihood function, i.e.,
$$
\hat{L} = \left( 2\hat{\sigma}^2 \pi \right)^{n/2}\exp\left\{ -\sum(y_i - \hat{y}_i )^2/(2\hat{\sigma}^2)\right\},
$$
where $\hat{y}_i = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1x_i$ and $\hat{\sigma}^2 = \frac{1}{n}\sum (y_i - \hat{y}_i)^2$,hence 
$$
\hat{L} = \left( 2\hat{\sigma}^2 \pi \right)^{n/2}\exp\left\{ -n/2\right\}.
$$